# Unity Ambient Occlusion not working with Orthographic camera

Tags: unity, lighting, post-processing, ambient-occlusion

It seems like the `Ambient Occlusion` setting from the Unity Post Processing stack (obtained from the asset store) only works with a Perspective camera, yet I haven't come across any documentation stating that this is the case or that it lacks support for Orthographic.

All the other settings in the stack seem to be working in both Perspective and Orthographic.

Is this a bug, or something I'm not doing right or understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here but SSAO is dependent on the depth buffer of the camera. Since a orthographic projection does not take into consideration the distance of the object from the camera this will result in a depth buffer that cannot be used with the SSAO shaders.

Comment: This is not correct. An orthographic camera still renders to a depth buffer to handle occluding geometry. The distribution of depth precision is different though (for perspective cameras, content far away takes up fewer pixels on screen, so lower precision depth is less noticeable there, but orthographic cameras can't hide these precision errors so easily and may require special handling to get good quality SSAO results in the distance)

Comment: @DMGregory I did not say that the ortho cam does not have a depth buffer, only that it's buffer might not be suitable for the SSAO from the post procesing stack.